# Regarding Date format

Tags: java, spring

Hi Can any one please suggest me how to write the date format,

```
dd MMM YYYY HH:mm
```

In Chinese.
For example I need

```
(2017 九月 28 11:30).
```

I want to set the date format in Hippo cms. Thanks

Comment: Your format start with `dd` but your expected output start from `year` can you more specific ?

Comment: Read [the javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  There are other constructors.  One of them takes a [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#CHINESE) argument.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simpleDateFormat

```html
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY hh:mm", new Locale("zh","CN"));
```

Comment: OP has `MMM`.where as your `MM`

Answer (score 0):

This will be the correct solution.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYYY HH:mm", new Locale("zh","CN")); 
Date d = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(d));
```

Ouput:-

```
23 八月 2017 21:16
```